# Clustering unrelated (with no correlation) data

Tags: python, r, matlab

The objective of clustering analysis is to group data with similar characteristics in clusters, but in this case, I want to find the most unrelated data to group into clusters. 
In my particular case I have 100 weather stations during one year with a 1hr interval, and I want to group the most similar weather stations(I performed this step with K-means using the correlation distance via Matlab, but I can use R or python). But now, I want to perform the inverse, i.e., group in the same cluster unrelated (with no correlation) weather stations .

This is possible? If yes, how? Or, should I use others techniques to execute my idea?

Thanks in advance!